# JQuery Data not able to print in html

Tags: html, jquery, node.js, handlebars.js

```
function loadMobMakes() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/makes",
        method: "GET",
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                var content = '';
                var makes = data;
                for (var make of makes) {
                    //console.log(product);
                    content += '<li>';
                    content += '<a class="py-7 px-30 text-dark d-block text-uppercase" href="/'+make.seo_url+'-used-parts" title="'+make.brand_name+' Used Parts">'+make.brand_name+'</a>';
                    content += '</li>';
                }
                $('#navMobMakes').empty().append(content).promise().done(function() {

                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is the Jquery Code and if we **console.log(content)** our data is beign printed in console but when we use that function as id in Node handlebars we dont get any results

The below code is of Node Handlebars

```
      <div id="shopByMakeCollapse" class="collapse">
        <ul class="list-unstyled fs-14 text-dark offcanvas_collapse_list m-0 columns-2 py-10 px-16" id="navMobMakes">
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Why you use promise with append ??

Comment: Removing promise dont do anything

Comment: Does the `#navMobMakes` element exist when the `append()` line is called? IS the AJAX request successful? Any errors in the console? What debugging have you donie?

Comment: try `console.log( $('#navMobMakes'))` for see if exist element

Comment: "...when we use that function as id in Node handlebars..." - I don't know what "function as id" means. Can you explain further what you are trying to do?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini yes the element exist when I `console.log( $('#navMobMakes'))`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes the function exists when `append()` line is called

Answer (score -1):

The solution is using `async: false,` after the `method` in ajax code so that it can execute in synchronization and print data if `async` is `true` the code is executed but the data dont displayed

Comment: `async: false` is deprecated, and for good reason, it locks up the UI while making the HTTP request.

Comment: @Quentin can you tell me a good method for it?